# Javascript $http dependency injection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm having some problems trying to make http calls inside the same javascript controller which it gives me the error: 'function is not defined'

If I move the function to the outside of controller, i can't use $http dependency.. So here's my problem...

What should i use?

I'm trying to call this function through an onclick event on a div that I created dinamically.

I've already tried this but it also does not work:

```
function MyController($scope,$http,$resource) {
    function activateSmartcase(deviceId) {
};
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You call this method from ng-click directive?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you showed us more code

Comment: Please add the HTML that is giving you the problem.

Comment: function declarations inside controllers are private to those controller. To  invoke a function from the [ng-click directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), the function must be attached to `$scope` or the `this` context depending on how the controller is invoked, either vanilla syntax or controllerAs syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you call this method from `ng-click` directive than it should be attached to `$scope`

```
$scope.activateSmartcase=function(deviceId){

}
```

Comment: i'm using onclick.. when i use ng-click it doesn't work.. and i have the angular libraries.. i don't know what's happening lol

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('NameOfTheController', Controller);

        function Controller($scope,$http,$resource){
            const vm = this;
            vm.activateSmartcase = function(){
            /*code block*/
            }
        }

})();
```

Comment: where should I put the function that'll call with onclick? thanks :)

Comment: This link will be useful https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

Comment: it doesnt work.. I think you didnt understand my problem.. I've already have a controller.. can i create another one? I think i don't.

Comment: check my new post please :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309588/javascript-controller-function-is-not-defined